# App rejection with Message "Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness"

Tags: in-app-purchase, appstore-approval, subscriptions

My app doesn't have enabled In-app purchases in Capabilities.But i've StoreKit framework implemented as legacy code .Now on submitting app,Apple is rejecting app with Message

> Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness
>
> We are unable to complete the review of your app because one or more of your in-app purchase products have not been submitted for review.

Is it necessary to remove all the StoreKit api calling code before submission?

Or

Is it a problem with subscription group created in iTunesConnect which was created for testing & not submitting for review??

Answer (score 2):

Yes.. Tried with submitting app again after removing StoreKit framework & It got approved by Apple.

So it is required to add in-app product if there is any reference to StoreKit in code or remove it before submission if you don't want to submit any in-app product.

Comment: Why would you add SK if there isn’t any purchases to be made in the app?

Comment: Actually we are using 1 code base for multiple client apps.so for one client , we used another payment mode . Storekit API were called but not getting used on basis of conditions. but apple didn't allow to have storekit reference even if it is not  referenced.